# The data didn't place at the right place

Tags: excel, vba

I want my data to start with row number 5 but instead, the data go straight to the bottom.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("BEAM SUM CONC")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

With ws
.Cells(iRow, "B") = TextBox1.Value
.Cells(iRow, "C") = TextBox2.Value
.Cells(iRow, "D") = TextBox3.Value
.Cells(iRow, "E") = TextBox4.Value
.Cells(iRow, "F") = TextBox5.Value
.Cells(iRow, "G") = TextBox6.Value
.Cells(iRow, "H") = TextBox7.Value

End With
End Sub
```

howw?

Comment: Does your sheet contain a table (`ListObject`)? It would seem so from your previous question. Finding the last row in a table requires looking in the *table*, not at `ws.Cells`.

Comment: no table just a column and row with border. im not set specific table for the sheet @BigBen

Comment: Specify `After:=ws.Range("A1")` in the `Find`? Or use `End(xlUp)` as you did previously. The linked thread shows how to properly find the last row. If you don't have a table, then I find `End(xlUp)` to be the easiest.

Comment: `End(Xlup)` doesn't work on another sheet. just one sheet only

Comment: Sure it works on another sheet.